# Filling an array causes the stack around the array to be corrupted

Tags: c++, arrays

I'm trying to fill a 4x6 array with random numbers between 0-25 using a for loop inside a for loop. A runtime error occurs after the array is generated- "Stack around the variable "grid" was corrupted. What is causing this to happen?

```
int grid[4][6];
for (int y = 0; y < 4; y++) { 

    for (int x = 0; x < 6; x++) {
        grid[x][y] = (rand() % 25); 


    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're writing out of bounds. Your loop can write, for example, at (5, 3), which is outside the bounds of the array. In order to fix this, use `x` for the outer loop and `y` for the inner loop.

Comment: Thank you. It is pretty obvious now that I see it.

Answer (score 1):

I think your indices are backwards, where you have x it should be y and vice versa

Comment: You're right. It's strange how simple problems are easily solved from an outside perspective.

Answer (score 0):

As the others have said, you've got the row and column indices backwards.  The reason this is a problem is that in C and C++, the 2D array access:

```
grid[x][y]
```

is treated as the equivalent pointer expression:

```
*(grid + (x*COLS + y))
```

In this case, since C and C++ use row-major ordering, COLS is 6.  Additionally, a 2D array is equivalent to a 1D array of size (ROWS * COLS), meaning that in this case you effectively can address elements 0 through 23 of that 1D array.

Now, looking at your loop structure, you can see that given the pointer arithmetic rule, you'll access element 24 (thus clobbering the stack) when x is 4 and y is 0--that is, *(grid + 4*6 + 0), or the 4th iteration of your inner loop.

Switch your loop order (0 <= x < 4 and 0 <= y < 6) and your problem will go away.

Answer (score 0):

```
int grid[6][4];
```

You can use `gdb`, `valgrind` or anything else to find out the reason of segmentation fault.